# How to groupby ndarray?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the DataFrame (just an example)

```
D = pd.DataFrame({i: {"name": str(i),
                      "vector": np.arange(i + i % 4, i + i % 4 + 10),
                      "sq": i ** 2,
                      "gp": i % 2} for i in range(10)}).T

  gp name  sq                                    vector
0  0    0   0            [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1  1    1   1          [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
2  0    2   4        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
3  1    3   9      [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
4  0    4  16        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
5  1    5  25      [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
6  0    6  36    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
7  1    7  49  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
8  0    8  64    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
9  1    9  81  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

and I want to group by the column vector and then column gp. How can I do this?

```
from dfply import *
D >>\
    groupby(X.vector, X.gp) >>\
    summarize(b=X.sq.sum())
```

results in

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need convert column `vector` to tuples first in `pandas`:

```
print(D['sq'].groupby([D['vector'].apply(tuple), D['gp']]).sum().reset_index())
                                     vector  gp   sq
0            (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)   0    0
1          (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)   1    1
2        (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)   0   20
3      (6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)   1   34
4    (8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)   0  100
5  (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)   1  130
```

Another solution is convert column first:

```
D['vector'] = D['vector'].apply(tuple)
print(D.groupby(['vector','gp'])['sq'].sum().reset_index())
                                     vector  gp   sq
0            (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)   0    0
1          (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)   1    1
2        (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)   0   20
3      (6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)   1   34
4    (8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)   0  100
5  (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)   1  130
```

Anf if necesary last convert to `array` back:

```
D['vector'] = D['vector'].apply(tuple)
df = D.groupby(['vector','gp'])['sq'].sum().reset_index()
df['vector'] = df['vector'].apply(np.array)
print (df)
                                     vector  gp   sq
0            [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]   0    0
1          [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]   1    1
2        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]   0   20
3      [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]   1   34
4    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]   0  100
5  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]   1  130

print (type(df['vector'].iat[0]))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I try use your code and for me works:

```
from dfply import *

D['vector'] = D['vector'].apply(tuple)
a = D >> groupby(X.vector, X.gp) >> summarize(b=X.sq.sum())
a['vector'] = a['vector'].apply(np.array)
print (a)
   gp                                    vector    b
0   0            [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]    0
1   1          [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]    1
2   0        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]   20
3   1      [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]   34
4   0    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]  100
5   1  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]  130
```

Answer (score 4):

`list`s are **not** hashable... `tuple`s are.  We want to group by a tuplified version of the `vector` column.  I'll use a list comprehension.

```
D.groupby([[tuple(x) for x in D.vector], 'gp']).sq.sum()

                                          gp
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)            0       0
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)          1       1
(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)        0      20
(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)      1      34
(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)    0     100
(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)  1     130
Name: sq, dtype: int64
```

---

To get it back into the original form... one of many ways

```
d1 = D.groupby([[tuple(x) for x in D.vector], 'gp']).sq.sum()
d1.reset_index('gp').rename(index=list).rename_axis('vector').reset_index()

                                     vector  gp   sq
0            [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]   0    0
1          [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]   1    1
2        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]   0   20
3      [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]   1   34
4    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]   0  100
5  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]   1  130
```

Answer (score 0):

a little odd way

```
D.groupby([D.vector.apply(str), D.gp]).sq.sum().reset_index()
```